# OpenJPA CascadeType.DELETE causes Foreign Key constraint violation

Tags: foreign-keys, openjpa, cascading-deletes

I am using OpenJPA (JPA 1.0) on WebLogic 10.0.x with Oracle. I have defined a OneToMany relationship as below:

```
@Entity
public class Compound implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="compound", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Submission> submissions = new ArrayList<Submission>();
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Submission implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name="compoundId")
    private Compound compound;
    ...
}
```

When I delete a Compound entity all child Submission entities should be deleted also. This works as a general rule, except that I have a foreign key constraint setup on these tables:

```
ALTER TABLE SUBMISSION
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SUBMISSION_COMPOUND
    FOREIGN KEY (COMPOUNDID)
    REFERENCES COMPOUND(COMPOUNDID);
```

Now when I attempt to delete the Compound entity I encounter the following exception:

```
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (HELC.FK_SUBMISSION_COMPOUND) violated - child record found {prepstmnt 3740 DELETE FROM Compound WHERE compoundId = ? [params=(long) 10384]} [code=2292, state=23000]"
```

The above exception implies that Open JPA is attempting to delete the parent prior to cascading the delete onto the child entities. I've read a few articles via Google about this exception, dating back to 2006. However, the most recent article suggests that this bug has been fixed?

[http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/openjpa-dev/200609.mbox/%3C14156901.1158019042738.JavaMail.jira@brutus%3E](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-235)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-235

Can anyone suggest why this is not working and what I can do about it? I am loathe to manually delete the child entities, especially as this is one of the less-complicated relationships in my schema and whatever solution I use for this I will need to apply elsewhere.

Thanks
Jay

Comment: How much experience do you have in OpenJPA? Is it possible that your CascadeType in Submission is wrong?

Comment: OpenJPA? Not much. I don't know if a cascade definition is even needed in the Submission class? This is a dependent entity, so it should be deleted if the parent (Compound) entity is deleted but deleting the Submission should not delete the parent. So far as I can tell my code is correct.

Comment: One thing - as discussed above this is Weblogic 10.0.x. I suspect we are using the bundled version of OpenJPA / Kodo, which is probably quite old...

Comment: I think that's old enough that you might not have that bug fix. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> When I delete a Compound entity all child Submission entities should
>   be deleted also. This works as a general rule, except that I have a
>   foreign key constraint setup on these tables:

If you can change the foreign key constraint, that should solve the problem as far as the database is concerned. I'm not sure how OpenJPA will behave here.

```
ALTER TABLE SUBMISSION
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SUBMISSION_COMPOUND
    FOREIGN KEY (COMPOUNDID)
    REFERENCES COMPOUND(COMPOUNDID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

> One thing - as discussed above this is Weblogic 10.0.x. I suspect we
>   are using the bundled version of OpenJPA / Kodo, which is probably
>   quite old...

My own feeling is that the bug you referred to should have been fixed by this version, but it's also a) close enough in time that it might not have been fixed, and b) potentially a big enough problem that I think you should spend some time verifying the version and fix.  (Actually, I just noticed that [OpenJPA 1.0 was released on Aug 2007](http://openjpa.apache.org/downloads.html). That's a lot earlier than I thought, which makes it more likely you don't have the bug fix.)

If you can't modify the database (because it's a legacy system that clearly doesn't intend for clients to rely on cascading deletes), and if the bug isn't fixed in your version, you'll have to manage the order of SQL statements yourself.

The burden of manually managing SQL statements--which is one of the things that OpenJPA is supposed to do *for* you--might be enough to get management to either upgrade OpenJPA or to update the foreign key constraints in the database.

I really hope you get a better answer than this one.

Comment: Hi Catcall. I tried that already actually. It appeared to work at first but then I started getting error messages from JPA saying that the child entities had been modified outside of the transaction context (I've mislaid the exact error message). Also, I'm a bit reluctant to add a delete cascade on the database.

Comment: Was that constraint generated by OpenJPA?

Comment: No, this is a legacy database, I am creating a front-end for it. That is also one reason why I am reluctant to add an on delete cascade clause unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks again for your response Catcall. I think you are right. The versions in modules directory are org.apache.openjpa_1.0.0.jar, com.bea.core.kodo_4.1.3.1.jar, com.bea.core.kodo.integration_1.0.1.0.jar, com.bea.core.kodo.integration.tools_1.0.1.0.jar. They don't sound particularly recent :(